# Play Framework Module Manual Change

Tags: heroku, playframework

I have a module that I'm using in my Play! application, but have needed to make certain tweaks to it to work for my needs.  I am also using Heroku for my host, so whenever I deploy, it runs a "play deps" and blows away my manually built lib.

Is there any way I can get my manual changes to Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Play 1.x**:

Your `modules` directory should not be in your git repo.  Instead you should setup a file repository that Play will use to resolve the dependency.  In your `conf/dependencies.yml` do something like:

```
require:
    - play
    - localModule -> foo 0.3

repositories:
    - local repo:
        type: local
        artifact: "${application.path}/local-repo/[module]-[revision].zip"
        contains:
            - localModule -> *
```

Then put a file like `foo-0.3.zip` in a new `local-repo` directory in your project.  You can test it locally by running:

```
play deps --sync
```